# Reshape matrix with zeros padding

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am working with matrix using reshape function. I have a matrix size `990 x 8`. First, I will reshape it to `A x 400` where A will be determined s.t 990x8 is devisible by 400. So, we must add 80 zeros as padding. So, A is

```
 (990+10)/400=200
```

My new matrix is `20 x 400`. Now I set one row as error row in A. Second step, I want to recovery my orignal matrix size 990 x 8 with that row error. So, the number row error will be

```
400/8=50 rows
```

It is very clear when you see the below figure. Now I want to implement this scheme by matlab code. Let see my implementation as bellow. However, it does not similar my goal. It appeared some -1 in individual row (ex: [0 0 -1 0 0 ..], the true answer must be [0 0 0...] or [-1 -1 -1..] because if row without error will only constain 0 or 1, and error row is only -1 values). Please fix help me

```
    bitstream = reshape( orignalPacket.', [],1); %size 990 x 8
    %% Add padding        
    bitstream(end+80)=0; % add zeros padding at the end
    %% New matrix 20 x 400
    newmatrix= reshape( bitstream.', [],psize);
    %% Add one error row
    newmatrix(5,:)=-1; %row 5th is error

    %% Recovery to orignal packet
    bitstream_re = reshape( newmatrix, [],1);
    bitstream_re(end-80+1:end)=[];%% Remove padding
    matrix_re=reshape(permute(reshape(bitstream_re,size(bitstream_re,2),8,[]),[2 1 3]),8,[]);
    matrix_re=matrix_re'; %Recovery matrix-
```

Comment: In the third step is the zero padding suppose to be constrained to a single line? So the last line is 320 + padding?

Comment: +1 for good effort on explaining, a rarity these days.

Comment: @Ayb4btu: 80 zeros padding are added that mean 10 lines, sir. Because total lines (rows) of orignal matrix is not devisible by 400

Comment: @user8264 In your diagram I understand the need for the 10 lines of padding shown in the second step. But reshape (depending on the transpose) will either put all the zeros in the last 4 columns, or for half a column every 50 columns. The third step implied you wanted the padding on the last row. For the third step in your diagram, where did you want the padding?

Comment: Sorry, I think it is end of line. Because I think orignal padding is at the end, so after reshape, it will still at the end of matrix. Has some mistake?

Comment: To make all your rows consistent (which you probably want if you are changing a single row), then I assume you want the padding in the last four columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems you were encountering were because MATLAB uses column-major indexing and with your operations you were indexing into the matrices row-wise.

Here's the modified code that seems to work -

```
error_row = 5; %// row index to be set as error row

bitstream = orignalPacket; %// Assuming orignalPacket is of size 990 x 8

bitstream(end+10,:)=0; %// pad with 10 rows of zeros at the end

%// New matrix 20 x 400
newmatrix = reshape(bitstream.',400,20).';

%// Add one error row
newmatrix(error_row,:)=-1; %// row 5th is error

%// Recovery orignal packet
bitstream_re = reshape(newmatrix.',1,[]); %//'
bitstream_re(end-80+1:end)=[]; %// Remove padding

matrix_re = reshape(bitstream_re,8,[]).'; %//'# Recovered matrix
```

By the way, you can achieve the same output `matrix_re` without all these reshaping and tedious indexing with this -

```
matrix_re = orignalPacket; %// Assuming orignalPacket is of size 990 x 8
error_row = 5; %// row index to be set as error row
matrix_re(50*(error_row-1) + 1 :50*error_row,:) = -1;
```

Comment: bitstream(end+10,:)=0;  It is plus 10 or 80. I think it is 80 zeros padding.

Comment: @user8264 From the diagram it seems you intend to pad 10 rows of zeros, so I guess `bitstream(end+10,:)=0;` makes sense, doesn't it?

Comment: sorry, maybe I mistake. The above code, I convert to sigle row bitstream = reshape( orignalPacket.', [],1); %size 7920 x 1 ,then I add 80 padding. But you are don't convert to single row, I think you correct

Comment: @user8264 Yeah, I am keeping the 2D format and then padding, and since the first index is the row index, I am extending the number of rows and the number of columns automatically gets extended/padded because as the second index I am using `:`.

Comment: @user8264 The update code must make more sense, check it out.